# SQL query database on column data type with a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For example, in SQL Server(10.0.5520. SQL Server 2008 SP3), we have a table with 3 columns of type `DateTime`.

Our goal is get only data which has one of 3 columns > `SpecificedDate` but we don't want list out specified columns one by one.

Please view an example below:

```
TABLE A (ID INT, 
         Name VARCHAR, 
         CreateDate DATETIME, 
         ModifyDate DATETIME, 
         VoidDate DATETIME)
```

Normally it will be:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE CreateDate > 'X' OR ModifyDate > 'X' OR VoidDate > 'X'
```

It should turn to

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE (IF Column Is DateTime AND Column.Data > 'X')
```

Can we query in that way? If yes, how can we do that?

Comment: What is your database,sql is just the language.Sql server or mysql or oracle?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please view the edited question again, sorry for the question is not cleared. I just edited

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Don't you know the table on before hand?

Comment: Why `IF Column Is DateTime` when all columns are date types? ` CreateDate DATETIME, ModifyDate DATETIME, VoidDate DATETIME`

Comment: @Patrick Hofman: sometimes, I don't know table structure, task simple get data which has specified date if it has column with data type is DATETIME

Comment: Which version of Sql Server?

Comment: It's 10.0.5520.  SQL Server 2008 SP3

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri: I edited table for clearer

Comment: Do you want the data from the row when ONLY one column is filled? Or do you want the data from the row where MINIMUM one datecolumn is filled?

Comment: @KarmaEDV: It's minumum one date-column is filled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sys.columns` to get the columns for a given table that is `datetime`.

```
select C.name
from sys.columns as C
where C.object_id = object_id('A') and
      C.system_type_id = type_id('datetime')
```

Then you can use that to build and execute your query using `sp_executesql`.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

set @SQL = '
select *
from dbo.A
where '+stuff((
              select 'or '+quotename(C.name) + ' > @Value '
              from sys.columns as C
              where C.object_id = object_id('A') and
                    C.system_type_id = type_id('datetime')
              for xml path(''), type
              ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 3, '')


--print @SQL

exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Value datetime', '2015-07-01'
```

---

```
select *
from dbo.A
where [CreateDate] > @Value or [ModifyDate] > @Value or [VoidDate] > @Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Table A

```
ID  Name        CreateDate              ModifyDate              VoidDate
--- ----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1   Name1       2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 2015-02-02 00:00:00.000 2015-03-03 00:00:00.000
2   Name2       2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL                    NULL
3   Name3       NULL                    NULL                    2015-03-03 00:00:00.000
4   Name4       NULL                    NULL                    NULL
```

T-SQL Code

```
DECLARE @ColNames AS TABLE (RowNumber INT, ColumnName VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @ColNames
    SELECT 
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY c.COLUMN_NAME) AS RowNumber,
        c.COLUMN_NAME
    FROM 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    WHERE
        TABLE_NAME = 'A' AND DATA_TYPE = 'datetime'
    ORDER BY RowNumber

DECLARE @SpecifiedDate DATETIME
SET @SpecifiedDate = '2015-01-01'

DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @sqlString NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM A WHERE '

DECLARE @count INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @ColNames)

WHILE @i <= @count
BEGIN
    DECLARE @colName VARCHAR(MAX) =
        (SELECT ColumnName FROM @ColNames WHERE RowNumber = @i)

    SET @sqlString = @sqlString + @colName + ' > ''' 
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @SpecifiedDate,104) + ''''

    SET @sqlString = @sqlString + 
        CASE WHEN @i < @count 
            THEN ' OR ' 
            ELSE '' 
        END

    SET @i = @i + 1;
END

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlString, N'@SpecifiedDate datetime', '2015-01-01'
```

Output

```
ID  Name   CreateDate              ModifyDate              VoidDate
--- ------ ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1   Name1  2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 2015-02-02 00:00:00.000 2015-03-03 00:00:00.000
3   Name3  NULL                    NULL                    2015-03-03 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Sql Server 2012+` you can use `TRY_CAST` function:

```
WHERE TRY_CAST(column1 AS DATETIME) > 'X' OR
      TRY_CAST(column2 AS DATETIME) > 'X' OR
      TRY_CAST(column3 AS DATETIME) > 'X'
```

In `Sql Server 2008` you can use `ISDATE` function:

```
WHERE (ISDATE(column1) = 1 AND CAST(column1 AS DATETIME) > 'X') OR
      (ISDATE(column2) = 1 AND CAST(column2 AS DATETIME) > 'X') OR
      (ISDATE(column3) = 1 AND CAST(column3 AS DATETIME) > 'X')
```

Comment: Hi Giorigi, how about if I don't know column name?